# what is the Meaning of %i in the code **frames=[PhotoImage(file="chatgif.gif",format="gif -index %i" %(i)) for i in range(20)]**

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to understand this line of code. Please help

```
frames=[PhotoImage(file="chatgif.gif",format="gif -index %i" %(i)) for i in range(20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`%i` is [string formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). Here it creates 20 strings `"gif -index <NUMBER>"`, where number is from 0 to 19:

For example:

```
for i in range(10):
    print( "gif -index %i" % (i) )
```

Prints:

```
gif -index 0
gif -index 1
gif -index 2
gif -index 3
gif -index 4
gif -index 5
gif -index 6
gif -index 7
gif -index 8
gif -index 9
```

---

EDIT (Thanks to @blckknght): An alternative with `str.format()`:

```
frames=[PhotoImage(file="chatgif.gif",format="gif -index {}".format(i)) for i in range(20)]
```

Comment: You might want to translate the code into more modern examples using `str.format` or f-strings.